# How do you designate a Currency literal in VBA

Tags: vba, ms-access

If I wanted to define a Date literal, I would write the following:

**Dim myDate as Date = #1/1/2021#**

What character should I use to do an analogous thing for a Currency variable?
That is

**Dim amt as Currency = ?200.00?**
What character should "?" be when using VBA?

Comment: `Dim myDate as Date = #1/1/2021#` is not valid VBA.

Comment: There is no delimiter for Currency, its just a number.

Comment: According to the linked Q and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/currency-data-type it is `@`

Comment: @TimWilliams I don't think OP is trying to use type hints here.

Comment: OK my bad jumped the gun a bit...

Comment: Not your bad... the wording confused me too. Plus the code snippet looks like VB.Net.

Comment: You can simply assign the currency type a number - VBA will auto cast the number. So at the end of the day, if you define a currency type, anything you assign to it, if legal WILL RESULT in a currency data type - in effect once you defined the data type as currency, then you are good to go.  So, simply use + assign the variable a number - any legal currency number and you are good to go. As outlined below, you can use the older legacy #, @ etc. (@ for currency - but it not really required in most cases if you strong typed the variable).

Answer (score 5):

In VBA a declaration cannot legally be joined with an assignment in the same instruction, so that would be:

```
Dim myDate As Date
myDate = #1/1/2021#
```

For the sake of this discussion it's important to differentiate the *variable* from the *literal value*, because the declared type of the variable is irrelevant to the type of the literal - this is perfectly confusing, but perfectly legal too:

```
Dim myDate As Long
myDate = #1/1/2021#
```

We're talking about the literals here.

A numeric literal is an `Integer` literal if it's between -32767 and 32767, a `Long` literal if it's between -2147483647 and 2147483647, and a `Double` otherwise (the VBE automatically adds a `#` type hint then).

That means the `200` in `myAmount = 200` is an `Integer` literal, and if we typed `200.00` the VBE would "prettify" it to `200#` (making it a `Double` literal).

The type hint character to use for a `Currency` literal, is `@`, so the `200` in `myAmount = 200@` is a `Currency` value that the VBA compiler understands as such.

It doesn't matter though, because VBA will do lots of *widening* (*narrowing* too) implicit type conversions for us: if we assign an `Integer` literal to a `Currency` variable, the `Integer` value is converted to "fit" the reserved `Currency` "bucket". So if we declared `myAmount As Currency` and then assigned it to the literal value `200` (an `Integer` literal), if we asked VBA what type `myAmount` is, we would get the declared type - `Currency`.

In other words it's perfectly legal to assign an `Integer` or a `Double` literal to a `Currency` variable, and that makes type-hinted literals somewhat awkward beasts that don't really belong, in the vast majority of situations:

```
Dim myAmount As Currency

myAmount = 200 'integer literal
Debug.Print TypeName(myAmount) 'currency

myAmount = 200# 'double literal
Debug.Print TypeName(myAmount) 'currency

myAmount = 200@ 'currency literal
Debug.Print TypeName(myAmount) 'currency
```

Things get groovy when we drop the declared type and use a `Variant` instead (implicit or not):

```
Dim myAmount 'As Variant

myAmount = 200 'integer literal
Debug.Print TypeName(myAmount) 'integer

myAmount = 200# 'double literal
Debug.Print TypeName(myAmount) 'double

myAmount = 200@ 'currency literal
Debug.Print TypeName(myAmount) 'currency
```

A date literal needs `#` "delimiters" on both sides, because the `/` date separator character has another grammatical meaning in VBA (and many other languages too): in other contexts, it's the *division operator*: in a sense, `#` delimiters are more closely related to the `"` double quotes that delimit string literals, than they are to `@` type hints.

Comment: Note that type hints can also be used to declare the type of a constant, e.g. `Const myAmount = 5@`. The constant is not a variant in this case. That's one of the few cases where I sometimes use type hints to save some characters.

Comment: @ErikA a good point, although IMO `As Currency` scores much higher in terms of readability, than `5@` ...the few extra characters to type are worth it ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a list of VBA type-declaration characters I collected:

- `/` means no type-declaration character exists for that datatype.
- Also no type-declaration character exists for any composite data types such as arrays or structures.

| Type | Type-declaration character |
| --- | --- |
| Boolean | / |
| Byte | / |
| Currency | `@` |
| Date | / |
| Decimal | / |
| Double | `#` |
| Integer | `%` |
| Long | `&` |
| LongLong (64-bit VBA only) | `^` |
| Object | / |
| Single | `!` |
| String | `$` |

You can prove that for example in die Immediate-Window:

```vb
?TypeName(1%) 'Returns Integer
?TypeName(1&) 'Returns Long
?TypeName(1@) 'Returns Currency
?TypeName(1#) 'Returns Double
?TypeName(1^) 'Returns LongLong
?TypeName(1!) 'Returns Single
```